# use apt-get update E: Failed to fetch http://...... File has unexpected size

Tags: apt

```
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.kali.com/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (15320738 != 15317336). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 111.11.111.111 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:15317336 [weak]
    - SHA256:c4762e83455984f8d3fb54f6f42836808b8c891ba117661b61240bc5774d2e02
    - SHA1:fdebd56e7541e6f88d7910988ef694d3c409e21d [weak]
    - MD5Sum:51400b889af8677132f31d56f266bf22 [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 06:55:45 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

this is the error page.How to deal with this problem？

Comment: Hi Suden, I've encountered this same error, have you resolved it ?

Comment: I am having the same problem with my Kali VM.

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu and changing the repository mentioned in the error message fixed the issue, for me there was another mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved it. It seems that you added more than one source entries in /etc/apt/sources.list. I guess more than one entry will make apt command confused, likely get header from one source then get packages from another, and the package size may not equal to the one defined in header. Edit the file and left only one source entry worked for me. Hope this helpful

Comment: What command should we change?

Comment: You solved the theory, but did not provide the command to do this.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Here is my solution and it works on Kali inside VirtualBox.

Please update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Example

```
root@kali:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
root@kali:~#
```

Let's update it ...

```
root@kali:~# apt update
Hit:1 https://archive-3.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@kali:~#
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did the trick for me. The only change I made was upgrading all instances of `http://http.kali.org/` to `https://http.kali.org/`

Comment: Great comment, saved my day :)

Comment: This also worked for me

Comment: For me, In the terminal as root, I typed this command 
`echo "deb http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list` then `apt-get update`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the firewall is blocking it. For me it was the firewall detecting the packets as malicious.

Comment: Thanks for this, my Sophos UTM's default settings for web filtering were blocking this traffic as potentially malicious.

Answer (score -3):

First open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then delete all lines and add those lines

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

save and execute again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This leads to an error after `sudo apt-get update`:
`root@kali:~# apt-get update
Err:1 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
E: The repository 'http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`